# SQL Query for Kace

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to make a SQL Query for the KACE Ticket System to Get all Tickets closed in a specific time range (like 2021-04-20 - 2021-04-29).

I'm really quite a noob in SQL so thanks for any help. I tried to modify this query but it didn't work so far. Heres the working Query for closed Tickets in last 30 days.

```
select HD_TICKET.ID, 
        HD_TICKET.TITLE ,
        HD_TICKET.DUE_DATE,
        CONCAT(IF(TIME_TO_SEC(HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED) >= TIME_TO_SEC(HD_TICKET.TIME_OPENED),
        TO_DAYS(HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED) - TO_DAYS(HD_TICKET.TIME_OPENED),
        TO_DAYS(HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED) - TO_DAYS(HD_TICKET.TIME_OPENED) - 1), 'd ', 
        DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME("2000-01-01 00:00:00",
        SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED)-TIME_TO_SEC(HD_TICKET.TIME_OPENED))),
        '%kh %im')) AS TIME_OPEN,
        HD_PRIORITY.NAME as PRIORITY, 
        HD_CATEGORY.NAME as CATEGORY, 
        HD_STATUS.NAME as STATUS, 
        HD_IMPACT.NAME as IMPACT,
        MACHINE.NAME as MACHINE_NAME,
        ifnull((select FULL_NAME from USER where HD_TICKET.OWNER_ID = USER.ID),' Unassigned') as OWNER_NAME,
        (select FULL_NAME from USER where HD_TICKET.SUBMITTER_ID = USER.ID) as SUBMITTER_NAME
        from HD_TICKET
        left join HD_CATEGORY on HD_CATEGORY_ID = HD_CATEGORY.ID
        left join HD_STATUS on HD_STATUS_ID = HD_STATUS.ID
        left join HD_PRIORITY on HD_PRIORITY_ID = HD_PRIORITY.ID
        left join HD_IMPACT on HD_IMPACT_ID = HD_IMPACT.ID
        left join MACHINE on HD_TICKET.MACHINE_ID = MACHINE.ID
        where HD_STATUS.STATE = 'closed'
        and HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
        order by HD_CATEGORY.ORDINAL, HD_PRIORITY.ORDINAL, HD_STATUS.ORDINAL, HD_IMPACT.ORDINAL, OWNER_NAME
```

Thanks for any Help !

Comment: *btw. I have no clue how this query works it's just the only one working i copied from somewhere ^^

Comment: this might help : https://www.garron.me/en/bits/mysql-select-from-range-dates.html